# How to remove "previous", "next" and "today" button in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've tried something like this

```
viewRender: function(currentView){

            $('body').remove('.fc-prev-button');
            $('body').remove('.fc-next-button');
            $('body').remove('.fc-today-button');

            }
        });
```

But it doesn't remove those buttons. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to do it in fullcalendar configuration?

Comment: are you sure the call back method is being called?

Comment: intellij shows it gray so probably not

Comment: just checked it with alert. It is being called

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/ - Just don't set `prev`, `next`, and `today` in the header configuration?

Comment: Post it as answer and I'll accept it, thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just don't have to set the options in the header. Something like that.

```
header: {
    left:   'title',
    center: '',
    right:  'today '
}
```

Take a look here:
[Fullcalendar doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/)

Comment: Update: 5.11.3 -> you need `headerToolbar` and [the new docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `prev`,`next` and/or `today` from `left`, `center` or `right` of header when initializing the calendar. An example of a header without `prev`,`next` and/or `today`:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: { // layout header
     left: '', 
     center: '',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,listWeek'
   },
   views: { // set the view button names
    listWeek: {buttonText: 'list week'}
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few lines of code to hide "previous,next and today" buttons and also hide the month view and hide Sat and Sun from the calendar in Mobile view (which I set to under 400 pixels width):

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var headerJSON = {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,listWeek' // view buttons on large screens
  };

var hiddenDaysArray = [];

if($(window).width() < 400) 
{
    headerJSON = {
        left: '', // hide prev,next today in mobile view
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridWeek listWeek' // hide dayGridMonth on small view
      };

    hiddenDaysArray = [0,6]; // hide sunday,saturday on small view
}   

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
  header: headerJSON,
  hiddenDays: hiddenDaysArray, // hide Sundays and Saturdays on mobile
  ...
```